# SSH into a jail takes so long

Tags: networking, freebsd, pf

I have only one ip address and so I get to my jail through NAT.
SSH to the host is lightning-fast but SSH to the jail is awfully long... Like 20 seconds between ssh command and prompt for public key password :-s

In pf.conf :

```
rdr pass log (all) on $ext_if proto tcp to port $jail_ssh -> $jail_ip port ssh

pass log (all) quick on $ext_if proto tcp to port $host_ssh
```

Tcp dumps are the same except the 20 seconds time gap...
sshd configs are equal..!

Comment: Did you disable DNS in the sshd_config for the jail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeay! Good point, Andrew! The jail couldn't resolve anything since I forgot to nat jail traffic! `nat pass on $ext_if from $jail_network -> ($ext_if)` was missing in pf.conf :-s